# How do I get the word density of my text using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is where I enter a text:

[image]

Upon clicking on the COUNT button, it goes to this page:

[image]

My text and word count got displayed. But how do I get the word density of this text using vanilla JavaScript, and actually display it on this page?

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Word Counter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="input-page">
            <h1>Word Counter</h1>
            <form action="">
                <textarea id="text" type="text" rows="22" cols="60"></textarea>
                <br />
            </form>
            <button onclick="displayText()">COUNT</button>
        </div>

        <div id="count-page" style="display: none;">
            <h1>Your Text:</h1>
            <p id="display-text"></p>
            <div id="word-count"></div>
            <div id="word-density">
                <h1>Word Density:</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const displayText = () => {
  const inputPage = document.getElementById("input-page");
  const countPage = document.getElementById("count-page");
  const text = document.getElementById("text");
  const textValue = text.value;

  if (text.value !== "") { // normal flow will continue if the text-area is not empty
    inputPage.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("display-text").innerText = textValue;
    countPage.style.display = "block";
  } else { // if the text-area is empty, it will issue a warning.
    alert("Please enter some text first.")
  }

  const countWords = (str) => {
    return str.split(" ").length;
  };
  const wordCount = (countWords(textValue));

  const renderWordCount = () => {
    const wordCountDiv = document.getElementById("word-count");
    wordCountDiv.innerHTML = "<h1> Words Counted: " + wordCount + "</h1>";
  };

  renderWordCount();
};
```

Comment: What do you mean with word density? Do you want a list of all the words in your text and how many times they appear? And do you want us to write the algorithm?

Comment: See [here](https://www.cssscript.com/word-density-counter/)

Comment: Word density by square pixel? What's the unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the word density like @SimoneRossaini told, simply use a list and save how many times you found each word. This ends up like this for example:

[image: Result of word density]

I modified your code and added the word density.

```js
const displayText = () => {
  const inputPage = document.getElementById("input-page");
  const countPage = document.getElementById("count-page");
  const text = document.getElementById("text");
  const textValue = text.value;

  if (text.value !== "") { // normal flow will continue if the text-area is not empty
    inputPage.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("display-text").innerText = textValue;
    countPage.style.display = "block";
  } else { // if the text-area is empty, it will issue a warning.
    alert("Please enter some text first.")
  }

  const countWords = (str) => {
    return str.split(" ").length;
  };
  const wordCount = (countWords(textValue));

  const renderWordCount = () => {
    const wordCountDiv = document.getElementById("word-count");
    wordCountDiv.innerHTML = "<h1> Words Counted: " + wordCount + "</h1>";
  };
  
  const getWordDensity = (str) => {
    let wordList = {};
    str.split(/[\s\.,]+/).forEach(word => {
      if(typeof wordList[word] == "undefined"){
        wordList[word] = 1;
      }
      else{
        wordList[word]++;
      }
    });
    return wordList;
  };
  const wordDensity = (getWordDensity(textValue));
  
  const renderWordDensity = () => {
    const wordDensityDiv = document.getElementById("word-density");
    
    let table = "<table>";
    for(let word in wordDensity){
      table += "<tr><td>" + word + "</td><td>" + wordDensity[word] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    table += "</table>";
    
    wordDensityDiv.innerHTML = "<h1> Word Density: </h1>" + table;
  };

  renderWordCount();
  renderWordDensity();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Word Counter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="input-page">
            <h1>Word Counter</h1>
            <form action="">
                <textarea id="text" type="text" rows="22" cols="60"></textarea>
                <br />
            </form>
            <button onclick="displayText()">COUNT</button>
        </div>

        <div id="count-page" style="display: none;">
            <h1>Your Text:</h1>
            <p id="display-text"></p>
            <div id="word-count"></div>
            <div id="word-density"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove commas and periods `.replace(/[,.]/g, "");`

Comment: Hey @dalelandry I would like to apply that good idea to my code. But could you please tell me where could I put it in my code?

Comment: @ZeddrixFabian That is in the `wordDensity` function. I modified my answer, as I said in the comment before, so **it is included in the posted code already**. It is the second line `str.split(/[\s\.,]+/)`. (It is basically the same as @dalelandry posted, just in another way. Commas and periods are removed because they count as word delimiters now too.)

Comment: Hey @miile7, I just wanna ask, what does the `str.split(/[\s\.,]+/).forEach((word)` means in Line 29?

Comment: The [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function creates an array that contains each word as a value. A word is defined by the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in the brackets which sais: "A word ends, when there is one or more spaces and/or a dot and/or a comma." The [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) goes through every entry in the array and performes the function with each value called "word".

Comment: I recommend to check out the links that I included in my previous comment. Also play around and use `console.log()` on for example `console.log(str.split(/[\s\.,]+/))` to understand what is happening. This is the way you learn to code :) Everyone of us did that (and probably still does) :)

Comment: Oh and hey @miile7, I just figured out that instead of having `str.split(/[\s\.,]+/)`, you can do this too: `str.split(/[\s.,]+/)`. Thanks for the reference anyway. It's a big help.

Comment: Oh, so I was a bit too wary with escaping. You're welcome. :)